# ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22'

Tags: server

I install python flow --model cfg/yolo_1_class.cfg --load yolov2.weights --train --annotation train/annotations --dataset train/images --epoch 500.

Comment: The libstdc++ symbol GLIBCXX_3.4.22 is present from version gcc-6.1.0 .... Seems you are using an old OS. Please edit your question to include Ubuntu version.

Comment: Example fix : https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.3 .... → `sudo apt-get install g++-7`